# How do I set a default file for `models.FileField()`?

Tags: django, django-models

How do I set a default file for  `models.FileField()`?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='mydocs', default=???)
```

The answer would appear to be:

```
myfile=models.FileField(upload_to='mydocs', default='mydocs/myfile.pdf')
```

However this does not result in the desired behaviour when creating a new object.

Whereas for other fields like `CharField` the `default=` value is displayed on a new form as the widget value. However for FileField it is not, it still results in "no file chosen":

[image]

So how does one set a default? Should we try to create a new FieldFile instance? Do we need to create a file object?

Comment: the default should be `mydocs/myfile.pdf` if it is stored in `mydocs`.

Comment: You should also set `blank=True` if you do not want to make it a default in the `ModelForm`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, yes it should be 'mydocs/myfile.pdf`, typo edited

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I want to to load `myfile.pdf` as the initial file object suggested in a form (which the user can override), so `blank=False, null=False` would be correct?

Comment: `blank=True` means that the user is not required to add a file in the form, not to set it on the empty string. So **`blank=True`** but `null=False` yes.

Comment: set default='myfile.pdf' & make sure you this file exist with same name in your server place

Comment: @AshishSondagar, yes once the object is created if there is no other input the default file is saved in the field. However, on creating the form the default value is not displayed as the initial value.

Comment: Nedd to handle in this way, Pass the object of image, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61985152/5994924

Comment: @AshishSondagar, how would you do that in a default attr?

Answer (score 0):

it might be that you didn't define the default MEDIA_ROOT in your django settings. Try to define it like that:

```
def get_default(self):
    if self.myfile:
        return self.myfile
    else:
        return settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/mydocs/myfile.pdf'

myfile=models.FileField(upload_to='mydocs', default=get_default)
```

in your settings.py, add:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

in your urls.py, add to the end:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thanks, why do you have `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` as a string in the default attr? If the file is being created on save, then the default reference is working isn't it?

Comment: I've edited the code, I hope it works now.  'get_default 'method has to be outside of your model class.